# Timer task implementing handler

Tags: android, timer, timertask, android-handler

**UPDATE** : The code is working only that I dint init the textview, but this question is answered so I cant remove it either. So I will leave this question  as it is for anyone trying to implement a `Timertask` with `handler` that makes use of `Looper.getMainLooper` that directly attaches it to the UI THREAD.

**OLD QUERY** :Hello guys I am trying to implement a timer that runs a task which has a handler.
I am using it to update the UI every second.
This is what I am implementing:

```
 private void setRepeatingAsyncTask() {

        handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        timer = new Timer();

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                               i++;
                            tview.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // error, do something
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(task, 0, 1000);  // interval of one minute

    }
```

when I make setRepeatingAsyncTask() on create or somewhere else like button clicklistner, etc either the timer or the handler is not starting.
Please help new to android!

Comment: 1000 is 1 sec , not 1 minute

Comment: @W4R10CK nope 1000 is 1 sec it is in ms PS: don't mind the comment

Comment: I'm saying the same. but the error placing of `,`

Comment: @W4R10CK the middle 0 is post delay which I don't want, and 1000 reps the time taken to execute the task

Comment: See where it says `error, do something`? Have you tried doing something there? Ignoring `Exception` is usually a bad idea.

Comment: @MikeM. damn was thumping my head all over the desk because I din't init the textview ..cant believe lost 2 hrs on that, lesson bad idea to ignore exceptions :(

Answer (score 0):

I used `Handler` to process the task every 1 sec, Using just `Handler`:

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            //some task

            handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); //looping is every 1 secs
        }
    }, 0); //initial delay of 0
```

Comment: I have tried doing it like your way but there is a slight delay in updating the UI which I dont want. Also there is this new thing Looper that I am trying out

Comment: Maybe the delay is because your UI is large or the loop is very fast.

Comment: got my code running was just a simple mistake, should have atleast notified a log for my exception regrets that's all I can say, bdw your is also useful as its straight forward for doing simple things. thanks for your time :)